# Haskell package version conflict trips up linker. How to solve?

Tags: haskell

I am playing around with [happstack-server](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server) and [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson).

When importing both modules in my project, `ghc` throws an error during linking:

```
Linking Main ...
duplicate symbol _fps_reverse in:
    /usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3_3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.0.2/libHSbytestring-0.10.0.2.a(fpstring.o)
    /Users/jan/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.4.0/libHSbytestring-0.10.4.0.a(fpstring.o)
duplicate symbol _fps_intersperse in:
    /usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3_3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.0.2/libHSbytestring-0.10.0.2.a(fpstring.o)
    /Users/jan/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.4.0/libHSbytestring-0.10.4.0.a(fpstring.o)
duplicate symbol _fps_maximum in:
    /usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3_3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.0.2/libHSbytestring-0.10.0.2.a(fpstring.o)
    /Users/jan/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.4.0/libHSbytestring-0.10.4.0.a(fpstring.o)

...Some more omitted for brevity...

ld: 11 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, both versions of bytestring exist on my system. Happstack was built a while ago, Aeson just today.
The specified bytestring dependency for Happstack is broad enough to use `0.10.4.0`. But I can't seem to get Happstack to use it.

I already tried reinstalling happstack with `cabal install --reinstall happstack-server` but that didn't help.

Any hints how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**:
As Daniel suggested in a comment, I tried the following:

```
~/development $ cabal install --reinstall happstack-server --constraint="bytestring == 0.10.4.0" --dry-run
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1 (reinstall) changes: bytestring-0.10.0.2 -> 0.10.4.0
blaze-builder-0.3.3.2 (new version)
blaze-markup-0.6.1.0 (reinstall) changes: blaze-builder-0.3.1.0 -> 0.3.3.2,
bytestring-0.10.0.2 -> 0.10.4.0, text-0.11.3.1 -> 1.1.1.3
blaze-html-0.7.0.2 (reinstall) changes: blaze-builder-0.3.1.0 -> 0.3.3.2,
bytestring-0.10.0.2 -> 0.10.4.0, text-0.11.3.1 -> 1.1.1.3
parsec-3.1.5 (new version)
network-uri-2.6.0.0 (new package)
system-filepath-0.4.12 (new version)
unix-2.7.0.1 (new version)
directory-1.2.1.0 (new version)
network-2.6.0.1 (new version)
process-1.2.0.0 (new version)
hslogger-1.2.4 (reinstall) changes: directory-1.2.0.1 -> 1.2.1.0,
network-2.4.1.2 -> 2.6.0.1, process-1.1.0.2 -> 1.2.0.0, unix-2.6.0.1 ->
2.7.0.1
sendfile-0.7.9 (reinstall) changes: bytestring-0.10.0.2 -> 0.10.4.0,
network-2.4.1.2 -> 2.6.0.1
utf8-string-0.3.8 (reinstall) changes: bytestring-0.10.0.2 -> 0.10.4.0
zlib-0.5.4.1 (reinstall) changes: bytestring-0.10.0.2 -> 0.10.4.0
happstack-server-7.3.8 (reinstall) changes: bytestring-0.10.0.2 -> 0.10.4.0,
directory-1.2.0.1 -> 1.2.1.0, network-2.4.1.2 -> 2.6.0.1, network-uri-2.6.0.0
added, parsec-3.1.3 -> 3.1.5, process-1.1.0.2 -> 1.2.0.0,
system-filepath-0.4.11 -> 0.4.12, text-0.11.3.1 -> 1.1.1.3, unix-2.6.0.1 ->
2.7.0.1
Warning: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
websockets-0.8.2.3
haste-compiler-0.3
zlib-bindings-0.1.1.5
io-streams-1.1.4.4
zip-archive-0.2.2.1
haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

This is weird, how could this break unrelated (not part of happstacks dependency tree) packages?

At this point, maybe it makes sense to completely wipe my Haskell environment and install everything from scratch?

Comment: Your `happstack-server` was built using the old `bytestring`, and `aeson` was built against the new version. Thus they don't work together. You need to build both with the same version of `bytestring`. Your reinstalling apparently used the old `bytestring` version again (for reasons I don't know). What does `cabal install --reinstall happstack-server --constraint="bytestring == 0.10.4.0" --dry-run` tell you? If it doesn't announce breakage, remove the `--dry-run` and try again.