# Haskell linking failure conflicting packages

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a ghci session that crashes on run due to a runtime link failure.
The error is as follows:

```
GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   __hs_text_memcpy
whilst processing object file
   C:\Users\trbauer\AppData\Roaming\cabal\i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3\text-1.2.0.4\HStext-1.2.0.4.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
 loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

The list of packages loaded is as follows:

```
...
Loading package text-1.2.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parsec-3.1.7 ... linking ... done.
Loading package process-1.2.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package text-1.2.0.4 ...
...
```

It seems that text is tripping over itself (1.2.0.0 and 1.2.0.4 are both being loaded).

My question: *How do I debug this*? That is how do I determine which package is loading each version of text?  `cabal info` doesn't seem to list direct or indirect dependencies.  The only question I could find regarding inferring package dependencies had no tractable solution. Hence, I am suspecting that everyone else approaches this differently.

Once I can figure out who depends on what can use a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592699/haskell-package-version-conflict-trips-up-linker-how-to-solve) (rebuilding the dependents on a common text version).

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `v2` or `v3` during `cabal install` to give a detailed output and that might help. For example https://gist.github.com/artella-coding/ad2de89c2b198f504da9 gives the detailed output of `cabal install network -j1 -v2` on windows